# Ocaml client-server: Client returns EAGAIN when attempting to connect

Tags: unix, ocaml

I am trying to establish a simple client-server in OCaml
between my computer and a friend's on utop. However, when I, the client try to connect to my friend's computer. The following is returned

`Unix.Unix_error (Unix.EAGAIN, "connect", "")`

We tried followed the following documentation https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora187.html as well as the ocaml API reference.

server code

```
  let s = socket PF_INET SOCK_STREAM 0 in
  try
    bind s addr;
    listen s 1000;
    s
  with z -> close s; raise z;;
val install_tcp_server_socket : sockaddr -> file_descr = <fun>
─( 17:17:32 )─< command 29 >─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # let working = install_tcp_server_socket (ADDR_INET ((inet_addr_of_string "10.128.156.94"), 5002));;
val working : file_descr = <abstr>
─( 17:17:52 )─< command 30 >─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # let (connect, client) = accept working;;
```

client code

```
utop # let s = Unix.socket (PF_INET) (Unix.SOCK_STREAM) 0;;
val s : Unix.file_descr = <abstr>
─( 17:54:10 )─< command 5 >──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # let s_addr = Unix.sockaddr ((Unix.inet_addr_of_string "10.128.156.94"), 5002);;
Line 1, characters 13-26:
Error: Unbound value Unix.sockaddr
─( 18:12:32 )─< command 6 >──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # let s_addr = Unix.ADDR_INET ((Unix.inet_addr_of_string "10.128.156.94"), 5002);;
val s_addr : Unix.sockaddr = Unix.ADDR_INET (<abstr>, 5002)
─( 18:13:55 )─< command 7 >──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # Unix.connect s s_addr;;
Exception: Unix.Unix_error (Unix.EAGAIN, "connect", "").
─( 18:14:31 )─< command 8 >──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop #
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code on two systems here and it works for me. The server side was Linux (Ubuntu) and the client side was macOS.

The `connect` call is not supposed to return EAGAIN. It's not one of the documented errors. However I see chatter on the net saying that the Linux kernel does this anyway "when the peer's backlog queue is full". Possibly if you snoop around in the log files of the server system you'll see something interesting.

You could also try with a smaller value for the size of the backlog queue. The code you're working from uses 3, but you're using 1000. It probably shouldn't matter, and in fact it probably won't make any difference. But it's the only unusual thing I see.

Comment: These were both windows machines, if that makes a difference.

Comment: It probably does make a difference. You might look up what the EAGAIN error is supposed to mean. Maybe there's a documented meaning in the Windows implementation. Otherwise my suggestions would be the same. EAGAIN is such a strange error that there might have been an event interesting enough to show up in the logs.

Comment: It meant "Resource temporarily unavailable; try again" according to the following https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html. Im thinking that it was able to find my friends computer on the internet, but if he set it to accept requests and his capacity was high enough, it should work theoretically.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means in general, but it might have a more specific meaning when returned by `connect`. It is not one of the errors normally defined (in Unix) for the `connect` operation. As I recall it was originally (decades ago) returned only by `fork()` to indicate that there were no available process slots at the moment.